# Unknown custom command in django 2.2

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with running the command in django 2.2. The application is in `INSTALLED_APPS`. I receive a message:

```
Unknown command: 'my_command'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Below is the structure of the project:

```
project/
    app/
       managment/
           commands/
               my_command.py
       models.py
       views.py
       ...
```

my_command.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'My custom command'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
    code here
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Folder should be called `management` but not `managment`. Check the example in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management)